# Why does numpy.datetime64 give an error with an array of years?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I am working with some data that has the date in the format 2017.08333. In the process of converting this to datetime objects I got an error when trying to convert the integer years to datetime.

```
np.datetime64(['2017','2018'])
```

The above fails with the error:`Could not convert object to NumPy datetime`

I was under the impression numpy functions were vectorized. Can someone explain why this doesn't work and how I can solve this? I have 3,000 dates to convert so something that doesn't involve a loop is ideal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create an array of dates, you could do:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.array(['2018', '2017'], dtype=np.datetime64))
```

**Output**

```
['2018' '2017']
```

A more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html)

Comment: Thanks, so much. I spent so much time trying to figure this out.

Comment: btw, use `dtype='M8[something_like_Y_or_D_or_s]'` if `numpy` cannot recognize the unit

Answer (score 2):

Some of them are. I'm not sure what your input looks like (list or np.array), but you could do something like

```
np.array(['2017', '2018'], dtype=np.datetime64)
```

or

```
my_np_array.astype(np.datetime64)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I have been grinding my gears for a while. I feel a little dumb for how easy this was.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` as additional too:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(list(map(np.datetime64,['2017', '2018'])))
array(['2017', '2018'], dtype='datetime64[Y]')
```